# Magento 2: How to set visitor_data and currency_code session value?

Tags: magento2, core-session

In magento 2, For check all current session in magento 2, when we print **print_r($_SESSION)** then some list of session are display inside browser.

Resultant session look like below,

```
Array
(
    [_session_validator_data] => Array
        (
            [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
            [http_via] => 
            [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
            [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36
        )

    [_session_hosts] => Array
        (
            [141.0.165.165] => 1
        )

    [default] => Array
        (
            [visitor_data] => Array
                (
                    [last_visit_at] => 2016-07-29 14:04:30
                    [session_id] => lc7db6me3qgvm0srirje5pj6c6
                    [visitor_id] => 5530
                )

            [_form_key] => R45hajbDrwRyg2MW
            [currency_code] => GBP
        )

    [customer_base] => Array
        (
        )

    [catalog] => Array
        (
            [last_visited_category_id] => 15
            [last_viewed_category_id] => 15
        )

    [adminhtml] => Array
        (
        )

    [checkout] => Array
        (
        )

    [message] => Array
        (
            [default] => Magento\Framework\Message\Collection Object
                (
                    [messages:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
                )

        )

    [admin] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I want to know how to set default session in magento? at which place currency_code and visitor_data session value are saved?

How can we set session inside default in above code?
Any idea would be appericiated.

Thanks.